# How to find the expression of the following partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus

The question is showing below:
Let $f(u,v,w)$ be a $C^3$ scalar valued function, and let $g(r,s)=f(r+s, r-s, rs)$. Give an expression for $\frac{\partial ^2g}{\partial r\partial s}$ as a function as a function of the partial derivatives of $f$ and the variables $u,v,w$.

Here is my attempt right now:

For $\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}$, we can apply the chain rule to get
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot(1) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cdot (-1) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial w}\cdot (r)$$

Then for $\frac{\partial ^2g}{\partial r\partial s}=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}) = \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial r \partial u} - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r\partial v} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial w}+r\cdot \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial r\partial w}$.

But I found out the variable $r$ still appear in my final answer. I am kind of lost what I should do next? Can anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:  You're forgetting the chain rule at the second level. Write $F(u,v,w)=\partial f/\partial u$ and apply the chain rule to $G(r,s)=F(r+s,r-s,rs)$. Then remember what $F$ really is and substitute in.

Comment: I didn't get it, cause I think $G$ is $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function, but $F$ is $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function. Why you just let $G(r,s) = F(r+s, r-s)$

Comment: Sorry. Sloppy on my part.

Answer (score 0):

*More explicit hint.*
$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial u}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v\partial u}\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial w\partial u}\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v\partial u}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial w\partial u}s.
$$
Do the same for $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial v}$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial w}$.

Comment: This notation on the left truly makes NO sense. $f$ is a function of $u,v,w$, so differentiating with respect to $r$ is not defined. The typical science abuse of notation is utterly confusing here. Write $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u(r,s),v(r,s),w(r,s))\right)$, if you want to make it crystal clear.

Comment: It makes no sense, is utterly confusing, but you understood it --- and I believe the OP will understand too, as I borrowed the notation from them.

Comment: You should teach the OP proper, correct mathematics, not incorrect mathematics.